# HAProxy URL Introspection

Tags: django, haproxy

I have an application where the URL of a request determines which server to forward the request to based on a memcache or database lookup. Currently, it is just round robin, but the state is only stored on one server and that server needs to get all requests with a certain field. So I want to achieve something like the following table:

- /Objects/ABC/ -> Lookup *ABC* in memcache, returns servera.local -> `Server A`
- /Objects/DEF/ -> Lookup *DEF* in memcache, returns serverb.local -> `Server B`

Is this possible with HAProxy? If not, what else can I use? I **really** don't want to duplicate the request from `Server A` to `Server B` if `Server A` got the request but `Server B` is responsible for it.

Another solution that might work for me, is if the application can return something that tells HAProxy which host to resend the request to.

Answer (score 0):

This goes in the frontend

```
acl use_backend1 path_reg ^/Objects/ABC/$
acl use_backend2 path_reg ^/Objects/DEF/$
use_backend backend1 if backend1
use_backend backend2 if backend2
default_backend normal_backend

backend backend1
    ....

backend backend2
    .... 

backend normal_backend
    ....
```

Something along those lines

Comment: That's close to what I need, but I need the regex and backend list defined in a database or memcache